# sql server 2012 merge values from two tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables

```
tblA(sn, ID int pk, name varchar(50), amountA decimal(18,2))
```

and

```
tblB(ID int fk, amountB decimal(18,2))
```

here: tblA occures only once and tblB may occure multiple time 
I need the query to display data like:

```
sn ID name AmountA   amountB Balance
1 1001 abc 5000.00           5000.00
2 1002 xyz 10000.00
  1002              4000.00  6000.00 (AmountA-AmountB)
3 1003 pqr 15000.00 
  1003              4000.00
  1003              3000.00
  1003              2000.00  6000.00 (AmountA-sum(AmountB))
```

Please ask if any confusion
I tried using lag and lead function but I couldnot get the desire result, Please help.

Comment: Would you find it acceptable if the running balance were shown on every line?

Comment: thanks Giorgos. please help me find the desire output.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: hi Tim, I want same as above, can you help?

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: This is not a very good database design, IMO, because it makes it very difficult to see when the debits happened relative to the credits.  Ideally, you would have one ledger table, in which each record contained an addition or subtraction from the total balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use a partition with an aggregate function (`SUM`):

```
SELECT t.sn,
       t.ID,
       t.name,
       t.credits AS AmountA,
       t.debits AS amountB,
       SUM(t.credits - t.debits) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.debits, t.credits) AS Balance
FROM
(
    SELECT sn,
           ID,
           name,
           AmountA AS credits,
           0 AS debits
    FROM tblA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 AS sn,
           ID,
           NULL AS name,
           0 AS credits,
           amountB AS debits
    FROM tblB
) t
ORDER BY t.ID,
         t.debits,
         t.credits
```

**Explanation:**

Since the records in tables A and B each represent a single transaction (i.e. a credit or debit), using a `UNION` query to bring both sets of data into a single table works well here.  After this, I compute a rolling sum using the difference between credit and debit, for each record, for each `ID` partition group.  The ordering is chosen such that credits appear at the top of each partition while debits appear on the bottom.

Comment: Good Idea but Data from tblB comes first, Can it be tblA first and tblB in next row? It comes like this: <pre>1 1001 abc 5000.00 0.00 5000.00
0 1002 NULL 0.00 4000.00 -4000.00
2 1002 xyz 10000.00 0.00 6000.00
0 1003 NULL 0.00 4000.00 -9000.00
0 1003 NULL 0.00 3000.00 -9000.00
0 1003 NULL 0.00 2000.00 -9000.00
3 1003 pqr 15000.00 0.00 6000.00 </pre>

Comment: This comment is not remotely helpful.  Please _describe_ what output you got, and why you think it's wrong.